# linked list insertion and sorting for C programming

Tags: c, linked-list, insertion-sort, insertion-order

Hello I am new to c so I had a few issues with my code. My code is supposed to display a menu which displays if you want to add, search, delete, or print all. This works however, my insertion part doesn't. When I select add and start typing the information I want the program crashes?

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
//#define max 100

typedef enum { diploma, bachelor, master, doctor } education;

struct person {  // a node to hold personal details
char name[30];
char email[30];
int phone;
education degree;
struct person* next;
} *head;


void branching(char c);
int insertion();
struct person *search(char *sname);
void deletion(char *sname);
void print_all();

char *x;

//Main Method
 int main() {  // print a menu for selection
 char ch;

do {
    printf("Enter your selection\n");
    printf("\ti: insert a new entry\n");
    printf("\td: delete an entry\n");
    printf("\ts: search an entry\n");
    printf("\tp: print all entries\n");
    printf("\tq: quit \n");

     ch = tolower(getchar());
     branching(ch);
    } while (ch != 113);

      return 0;
    }

  void branching(char c) {    // branch to different tasks
switch (c) {
case 'i':
    insertion();
    break;
case 's':
    printf("Enter an item to search");
    scanf("%s", x);
    search(x);
    break;
case 'd':
    printf("Enter an item to delete");
    scanf("%s", x);
    deletion(x);
    break;
case 'p':
    print_all();
    break;
case 'q':
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    }
  }

//insert entry
int insertion(){
struct person *p;
p = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));

if (p == 0){
    printf("There are no more places to insert.\n"); return -1;
}

printf("Enter name, email, phone, and degree:\n");
scanf("%s", p->name);
scanf("%d", &p->phone);
scanf("%s", p->email);
scanf("%i", p->degree);
p->next = head;
head = p;
return 0;
}

   //search method
   struct person *search(char *sname){
   struct person *p = head, *b = p;
   printf("Please enter the name you wish to search:\n");
    scanf("%c", sname);
    while (p != 0)
    if (strcmp(sname, p->name) == 0){
    printf("Phone: %d\n", p->phone);
    printf("Email: %s\n", p->email);
    printf("Degree: %s\n", p->degree);
    return b;
    }
    else{
        b = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("The name does not exist.\n");
    return 0;
}
    //delete entry
   void deletion(char *sname){
   struct person *t, *p;
   p = head;
   t = head;
   while (t != NULL){
      if (t->name == sname){
          if (t == head){//case 1
            head = t->next;
            free(t);
            return;
        }
        else{
            p->next = t->next;
            free(t);
            return;
        }
    }
    else{
        p = t;
        t = t->next;
      }
  }
   return;
 }

    //print
  void print_all(){
struct person *p;
p = head;
if (p = NULL){
    printf("No entries found.");
}
else{
    while (p != NULL){
        printf("%s", p->name);
        printf("%d", p->phone);
        printf("%s", p->email);
        printf("%s", p->degree);
        p = p->next;
      }
       printf("\n");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is there an error when it crashes?

Comment: scanf("%i", p->degree);  is missing &

Comment: Build a version with debugging information, and run it in a debugger. When a crash happens the debugger will stop at the location of the crash letting you examine and walk up the function call stack, and at each level examine local variables.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  The `typedef enum` is not required in C++.  Please remove the appropriate tag.  In C++, the syntax would be `enum education {/*...*/};`

Comment: sorry for being picky, but C and C++ are two distinct languages. To me this looks like C, but I am not sure....

Comment: Also, since you have the C++ tag, convert your `char []` data types to `std::string`.  You'll be thankful you did.  Many defects are injected because of incorrect use of C-Style strings.

Comment: Change the expression in your `do-while` statement to `while (ch != 'q');`.  Don't use numbers for characters; use character constants or literals.

Comment: It is just c sorry about the confusion, and there is not error it just crashes, I'll try the debugging again.

Comment: I ran the debugger and the error seems to be this: "First-chance exception at 0x0FB9BBC2 (msvcr120d.dll) in Hw6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: consider using a sentry node. see http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Answer (score 0):

The variable `x` needs to point to valid memory.  When you make the declaration: 
`char * x;`
The **pointer is uninitialized and could point to anywhere in the computer's memory range.**

This is why we recommend using `std::string` and the C++ streams, such as:

```
std::string x;
cin >> x;
// or 
std::getline(cin, x);
```

Remember, if you dynamically allocate memory for C-Style strings, you have to deallocate the memory.

Also, you need to specify a maximum string length for your input.  This is why `scanf` is an evil function.  If you must use `scanf`, prefer it's other family members, such as `fscanf(stdin)` or use a format specifier with the maximum size specified.

When comparing the C-style string you will need to use `strcmp`.  When copying the string, use `strcpy`.  If you use `std::string`, you could use assignment operator and relational operators (more convenient and safe).